# Does Elimination communication work and can it be practiced in a modern society?

Tags: children, parenting

Is the method of [Elimination communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elimination_communication) to bring up a baby without using diapers real and working?

And since it was "taken" from primitive tribes where the mother is with the baby 24/7 for a long period, can the same be achieved with a modern day society where many times after the first ~half year the child is left for long time with other caregivers like the grandparents or a nanny and not the parents?

And finally, can it be practiced in an environment with many children like a day-car/kinder-garden?

Comment: Might be better on parenting.SE

Comment: @mmw the topic has been brought up at least once: http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-can-i-potty-train-a-12-month-old/108#108

Comment: @David The discussion on “parenting” just assumes unquestioningly that elimination communication works – something which is explicitly questioned here. The link is still nice since it proves notability. Consequently I think this is a real question that’s well-suited on this site.

Comment: @konrad. The link was for reference, but The claim is not clear. EC is primarily focused on communication, and the central claim is that babies communicate when they need to poop or pee. If the communication is ignored, the baby will poop or pee anyway, so if a day care had 20 kids, it might be tough for the provider to respond to each one, but that does not contradict the basic premise of EC. And anyone who doesn't use diapers will almost certainly get poop or pee somewhere, like on the floor or bed or lap, primitive or not.

Comment: Can we try to word this question a little more constructively? Like removing offensive terms such as "[primitive tribes](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_culture)" especially since neither word is used in the Wiki article you linked to.

Comment: @SamIAm, The question comes from an article I read on an Israeli site in Hebrew written by an Elimination communication instructor. And she used the term primitive tribes. I link to the Wikipedia page and not the original article because of the language.

Comment: @David, Babies are able to communicate when they are hungry, and a care taker of even several dozens of children can feed them all. Is the "communication" of the baby is a real cry for attention that can be read by someone, or is it just being so close and tight to the baby to notice that he acts a little differently when he has to go to the toilet?

Comment: @IlyaMelamed it is not so much a "cry" as a "grunt"; unlike with food, a baby can deal with the issue on their own so it doesn't escalate to a cry. Most parents recognize the grunt when it happens, but don't realize that they can put the kid on a potty instead of just waiting to change the diaper.

Comment: @David, does that "grunt" is a real communication attempt or is it just the sound of the child pooping, just like grown people sometimes grunt while they are on the toilet?
And will the child hold for some time from when he signals that he needs to the toilet and when he actually poops, in order give his parents time to act, or not?

Comment: The "grunt" is just the sound of the child pooping. But at some point the child figures out to wait, and kids can learn to hold it at a pretty young age.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few individual case studies that seem to suggest it's difficult but possible.

They're far from perfect as evidence since they're self reported, but there's one case of a woman in Australia which is sufficiently detailed, seems to be independent of groups with a direct interest in advocating the technique, and contains enough caveats on the difficulties of the technique that it appears credible and has been reported as credible by mainstream media.

[This write-up gives a fairly straightforward summary](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/real-life-stories/mum-refuses-two-week-old-9987971?ICID=FB_mirror_main):

- > The cues she watches out for are cries/grizzling which become desperate when her baby needs to wee or poo.
  >
  > "I use a combination of common sense, instinct, timing and listening to my baby," she writes.
  >
  > "Often if I get it wrong and we have an accident it is because I haven’t listened. I will then kick myself for ignoring her vocal and physical cues."
- > "I [take her to the bathroom sink] then say 'wee, wee' and make the sound psss so this cues her to go to the toilet. If it’s a poo I say 'poo, poo'' she explains.
- > "I’m not sure if other people who practise EC liken it to toilet training a puppy but I think it’s very similar.
  >
  > "With my puppies I would take then to the grass and tell them to wee. Now when I need them to go the toilet, for example at night, I just put them out and tell them to do wee."
- > ...And if she ever takes too long to respond to her daughter's cues and she has an accident, Cindy makes sure to repeat the word "wee wee" so her baby knows to associate the action with the term.

There's a more detailed [first-person account by the woman herself on an Australian parenting site](http://www.kidspot.com.au/baby/baby-care/nappies-and-bottom-care/ive-never-used-a-nappy-on-my-baby-and-i-dont-ever-plan-to).

Neither mentions childcare centres, but the first-person account does mention using the technique in a cafe toilet when the baby was two weeks old (with the help of "my poor husband [who] is madly cleaning up what didn’t make it into the bowl"). For those sorts of details it's probably better to ask on the [dedicated Parenting site](http://parenting.stackexchange.com) or on one of the sites that promote the practice (three are linked in the above write-up but I can't vouch for their quality).

Those sites dedicated to promoting the technique also include and reference other first person accounts. Most of these seem to be from people with a direct interest in advocating the approach, or, quotes where it's not clear how much direct experience there is, so they're worth treating skeptially, but they do suggest it's possible, with caveats. For example, [TribalBaby.org" gives a first person E-book account](http://tribalbaby.org/elimination-communication-baby-pottying) of it working "part-time" in conjunction with (not instead of) "reduced reliance on" nappies. This fits the idea from above that it is *possible*, but isn't 100% reliable and does involved "accidents".

Comment: "Often if I get it wrong and we have an accident it is because I haven’t listened. I will then kick myself for ignoring her vocal and physical cues." This is what we call confirmation bias.

Comment: It could be, if the rate of accidents isn't also going down. But it does sound like the rate of accidents *does* go down over time (if it didn't, she'd be dealing with 'accidents' constantly and 'kicking herself' almost every time the baby passes a motion)

Comment: @user568458 you make it sound like the baby is a legislature.